# xbindkeys (xvkbd): stuck CTRL with Debian Stretch

Tags: debian, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard, mouse, xbindkeys

I am using `xbindkeys` with `xvkbd` to add some magic to additional buttons on my mouse which I can press with my thumb. For this, I have `xbindkeys` in my `~/.xsessionrc` and the following lines in `~/.xbindkeysrc`:

```
"xvkbd -text "\[Control]\[Prior]""
    m:0x0 + b:15
"xvkbd -text "\[Control]\[Next]""
    m:0x0 + b:13
"xvkbd -text "\[Control]t""
    m:0x0 + b:17
```

This setup was working perfectly for the past two years. After the upgrade from Debian Jessie to Debian Stretch I noticed that the control key sometimes appears to be still pressed after using the mouse button once. As a result, every key action `x` behaves as `Ctrl+x`. This also causes the mouse buttons to not work as expected.

- Debian 9 Stretch, amd64
- xbindkeys 1.8.6-1+b1
- xvkbd 3.3-1+b1
- Mate + xmonad

Comment: I have exact the same issue with xvbd 

But I'm using Arch Linux 

I use

    #up
    "xvkbd -no-jump-pointer -text '\A\C\[Left]'"
       m:0x0 + b:8
    
    #down
    "xvkbd -no-jump-pointer -text '\A\C\[Right]'"
       m:0x0 + b:9

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem on OpenSUSE 15.0 and have been using xbindkeys + xvkbd for probably 7 years now.  But now the ctrl key gets stuck.

My five minute solution after trying to figure out what patch or if there are other versions available for my distro was to switch to xdotool which did what I wanted (ctrl+w, ctrl+r from mouse buttons).

2021 update:
I've switched to xte, xdotool also was resulting in "stuck" keys in opensuse 15.3.  It seems xte works better:

```
"xte 'keydown Control_L' 'keydown r' 'keyup Control_L' 'keyup r'"
    b:9  
"xte 'keydown Control_L' 'keydown w' 'keyup Control_L' 'keyup w'"
    b:8
```